# Marionette query string change triggers route event

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

If I add new parameters to query string then route change event gets triggered and I don't want that to happen, how can i resolve this?

for example I have route '/#register' if I add new parameters like 'name = abc' then route becomes '/#register?name=abc' which is fine but it also triggers route change event.

Please note I am using window.location.hash to add the query string parameters.

Thanks,
MSK

Comment: It would help to see a little code.  What are you looking for the new route to do? Update your models? Render a different set of views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use Backbone Router's `navigate` method.

```
router.navigate('/#register?name=abc')
```

The `navigate` method takes a second parameter, a hash of options. One of these options is `trigger` with which you can trigger a route change.

Without passing `{ trigger: true }` your url will be updated without hitting your router callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

To change the URL and add a history entry without triggering a route:

```
Backbone.history.navigate('/#register?name=abc')
```

To change the URL without adding a history entry and without triggering a route:

```
Backbone.history.navigate('/#register?name=abc', { replace: true })
```

This is useful for providing bookmarkable URLs without adding a step to the user's back button history.